# form section to the left of the background image

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

I am trying to copy the design of https://www.wework.com/ banner section where there is a background image around width of 83.33% and a form section just above background image at the left position. I could show the form section above background image and also at the left position but not exactly to the following design where about 50-60% is outside of image.

[image]

for clear picture, please look at the site https://www.wework.com/

Here is how i have done

```
<section class="hero-section">
   <section class="form">
     <h1>Search Form</h1>
     <form>
       <input type="text" name="search" />
       <input type="text" name="location" />
       <button>Submit</button>
     </form>
   </section>
  <section class="img-background">
    <div class="image">
    </div>
  </section>
</section>

.hero-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  margin: 0 -12px;
  position: relative;
}

.form {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: calc(50% - 2rem);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  padding-left: 12px;
  margin-top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  width: 33.33%;
  order: 2;
}

.img-background {
  width: 83.33%;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  margin: 0 12px;
  order: 1;
}

.image {
  background-image: url("https://ctfassets.imgix.net/vh7r69kgcki3/3Rp8TadHuB4736bDSYrMk7/d5585f00041d9b38458e7f8fd77f56ae/Web_150DPI-2018_11_19_WW_SF_1047_0989_1157_2385__1_.jpg?auto=format%20compress&fit=crop&q=50&w=2250&h=1266");
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  padding: 9em;
}
```

for workaround, here it is https://jsbin.com/habugepado/edit?html,css

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a background image in a separate container after the form, why not make the image a background image on the outer wrapper(the hero-section)?
I adjusted the width of the background image container to 35% to give it enough space on the left so the form can be accommodated.

Here's the HTML

```
<section class="hero-section image">
   <div class="form">
     <h1>Search Form</h1>
     <form class="form-wrapper">
       <input type="text" name="search" />
       <input type="text" name="location" />
       <button>Submit</button>
     </form>
   </div>
</section>
```

The CSS

```
.hero-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  margin: 0 -12px;
  position: relative;
}

.form-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  max-width: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}
input {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.form {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 30px 30px 30px 10px;
  max-width: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: -60px;
}


.image {
  background-image: url("https://ctfassets.imgix.net/vh7r69kgcki3/3Rp8TadHuB4736bDSYrMk7/d5585f00041d9b38458e7f8fd77f56ae/Web_150DPI-2018_11_19_WW_SF_1047_0989_1157_2385__1_.jpg?auto=format%20compress&fit=crop&q=50&w=2250&h=1266");
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 35%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  padding: 9em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution and time. The separate container for background image because if i wanted to have image slider than i can use that container.